# RxJS pattern for initializing a toggle between two values

Tags: javascript, rxjs

I am trying to figure out a nice RxJS pattern for a toggle-style button/link that basically limits a view of an array.

It toggles between two values, one of which is static, the other comes from an Observable (is result of an http request actually, `this.itemsArray$`).

**ts**

```
this.toggleClicks$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.viewAllToggle.nativeElement, 'click')
      .scan(prev => !prev, false);

this.itemsArray$ = Observable.of([ /* array of any */ ]);

this.viewLimit$ = this.itemsArray$
      .withLatestFrom(this.toggleClicks$, (items, viewAll) => {
        return viewAll
          ? { nowLimit: items.length, otherLimit: 5 }
          : { nowLimit: 5, otherLimit: items.length };
      })
      .share();
```

**html**

```
Showing <span>{{(viewLimit$ | async)?.nowLimit}}</span>.
<span #viewAllToggle>Show {{(viewLimit$ | async)?.otherLimit}}</span>
```

It basically works, but the obvious problem is the initial value, which is not populated until the first click. Even if I add `.startWith()`

```
this.itemsArray$ = Observable.of([ /* array of any */ ]);
```

it does not help.

What am I missing?

Comment: I noticed you wrote `this.itemsArray$` and then `this.itemsArray` (no `$`).

Comment: it's a mere typo

Answer (score 1):

I did not get what you said about `startWith`. My understanding is that this should work :

```
this.toggleClicks$ = Observable.fromEvent(this.viewAllToggle.nativeElement, 'click')
      .scan(prev => !prev, false)
      .startWith (false); // OR TRUE, dont know what behaviour you seek

this.itemsArray$ = Observable.of([ /* array of any */ ]);

this.viewLimit$ = this.itemsArray$
      .withLatestFrom(this.toggleClicks$, (items, viewAll) => {
        return viewAll
          ? { nowLimit: items.length, otherLimit: 5 }
          : { nowLimit: 5, otherLimit: items.length };
      })
      .share();
```

Is that what you tried?

The tricky thing here (and pretty much undocumented) with the `withLatestFrom(obs$)` operator is that nothing will be emitted till `obs$` emits its first value. That is a logical behaviour as there is no value to be passed to the selector function (here in `viewAll`), and passing undefined by default might not necessarily be a sensible choice. If you know about the distinction between events and behaviours, the rationale behind this is that `withLatestFrom` is to be used with behaviours, which always have a value at any point of time.

Comment: Yes, that's what I tried and I also tried with `combineLatest`. In both cases, there's no effect until the first click of the button. Yet, before the first click I want the HTML to have a valid default state rather tha "Showing Show"

Comment: Best way to look is to post a jsfiddle. However, if you really use `Observable.of`, then your `itemsArray$` will only emit ONCE. If you want to emit one by one the values you should use `from`. Then, if you use `startWith` the way I wrote, what you describe cannot happen, and the easy way to see it is to add `tap` instructions to log whatever data flow through your stream. Have a look at https://jsfiddle.net/tmd4ksem/. So in short debug your application, knowing that the operators work the way they should.